# Icom IC-7100 amateur radio circuit - is this a designed short?

Tags: circuit-analysis, short-circuit

My Icom radio has suffered what appears to be an over voltage fault. It's brand new and it appears as if the DCDC charger/regulator in my car has generously donated extra electrons to the radio and auxiliary circuit. Shame.

Looking at the HV (Vin) path, there's a strange circuit design around the MCU reset circuit. There's an LDO circuit which I cant quite make sense of. It appears to be powered a current limited 5V supply, which holds the CE (enable pin) high when it's on?

But what is happening with the HV input into the CE pin on IC6402, Isn't there a designed direct short between the HV input and ground?

[image: IC7100 Reset Circuit]

Comment: It does seem non-sensical. What happens in the real circuit? Trying to decode what might be a drawing error won't fix your immediate problem.

Comment: What is an "Icom"?

Comment: @Elliot Icom is the brand name of an amateur radio manufacturer. The IC-7100 is a radio transceiver.

Comment: The DX-5R5H334U is a 0.33F 5.5V supercapacitor for memory backup.

Comment: Looks like a drawing error.

Comment: Hi Alex, I renamed your title because "repair" questions are frowned upon here. Your question is actually about a specific circuit, and so it's totally appropriate, but this way it won't get any undeserved downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be an error in the schematic. Looking at the PCB traces, pin 3 of IC6402 appears to be only connected to R6110:

[image: PCB side A]

[image: PCB side A+B]

[image: PCB side B]

It looks like C6721 is connected to pin 13 of IC7002 and IC7003 (with no connection to HV):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @BrianDrummond 's comment; it looks like a drawing error.

If you disregard the connection from IC6402's CE pin to the HV rail, the circuit makes sense. The CE pin is held high when 5V is present, and can also be held high for a while by the supercap C6103.

I don't know what the HV rail is used for elsewhere so it's hard to guess what the intention is. But it doesn't make sense to provide a hard short to ground from an "HV" power rail, and there's no reason at all to ground both sides of C6721.

ICOM is known for good engineering - perhaps I'm missing something. But I don't think so! :)

Sorry about your new radio. I'd call ICOM and see what they say. At the least, they should look at it under warranty and then determine if the problem is theirs or if it was due to your power supply. They might simply fix it regardless :)

---

I just thought of another possibility. Perhaps the HV rail is for functionality that has been omitted (or disabled) on this product. If HV isn't used, and if IC6402's VOUT is also not used, then that short could be an easy way of simply "turning off" those subcircuits.